# How to get the client IP address before accepting the connection in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, ip

I'm studing c++ socket programming...
The server program binds to a socket and starts listening for connection requests...ok now how can I list the IP addreses of the listened requests?
I know I can get the IP addresses after accepting the connections but lets say I don't wanna accept a connection from an specific IP address...

Comment: Shouldn't you use a firewall to manage this type of requirement?

Comment: Dude I'm programming !!!

Comment: I agree. This is what the multitudes of router/switch security provisions are for. I think the best you could do is close the connection right away if the IP is on your blacklist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For optimum performance, this would be solved by filtering in the network stack, but the details of doing that will depend on the operating system (this is not part of the socket interface and your application may generally not even have the rights to configure your network stack this way.)

The other opportunity is after the `accept`, by which time the connection is already accepted (CONNECT ACK) on TCP level.

I don't think you can do it in the middle phase where you would prefer that.  That however would not be very different from doing it after `accept` anyway.

Comment: I'm not an expert but isn't it dangerous to accept a connection just to get the IP address ?

Comment: @user1378573, at this point it's gone through the firewall and everything set up on the network that do all the checking on IP address etc.

Comment: @user1378573 - The `accept` call grants no one any new rights.  It just makes it possible to access an individual connection on your side through the socket API.  The other side can do relatively little to harm you; a denial of service attack, or detecting that your port is open.  But they could do the same even if you didn't "accept".  You cannot simulate a firewall on app level.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows only, you can use the conditional callback feature of WinSock2's [`WSAAccept()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaaccept) function to access client information before accepting a connection, and to even reject the connection before it is accepted.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of this (though I thought I know winsock2 very well). But I believe this specific things isn't supported natively by the TCP driver.

Answer (score 5):

This can't be done in terms of the standard socket API. On all platforms I know, the system actually **accepts** the connection (i.e. responds with SYN+ACK TCP datagram) **before** the application has a chance to monitor the pending request.

Comment: Unless you're using UDP, in which case you wouldn't even go through all that fuss.

Comment: So what does it do when it listens ? What kinda data does it gather then ?